# Access denied when i try to connect to mysql server

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect to a MySQL server using Query Browser.But, I am getting the following error message in the windows command prompt `Host is not allowed to this MySQL server instance` I tried everything that was suggested in STACK OVERFLOW like- GRANT commands and then trying to access. It might be a 'duplicate' question. But please do answer me.

```
 Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
  Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Admin>mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 211
 Server version: 5.0.95-community-nt MySQL Community Edition (GPL)

 Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

  Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
  affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
 owners.

   Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.


   mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'123.28.88.45' WITH GRANT OPTION;
   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
   mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'123.28.88.45' WITH GRANT OPTION
-> FLUSH PRIVILEGES
-> mysql -u root -p
-> \q
```

Answer (score 0):

try to login with `mysql -uroot -p` instead of `mysql`.
Your last Grant-Command fails, because you miss an semicolon.

BR
Chris